Not able to get proper value of tranfer list after changing select in material UI React
Hi In our project we are using react material Ui. We are using select and transfer list function in our Ui. We have condition that after changing Select value in dropdown right side of the tranfer list should prepopulate. Currently functionality wise it is working but when I try to print it is taking past prepopulated value for the transfer list. Below is my code.Can someone please help me? Let me know If I need to add any other details
 <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Rank</InputLabel>
                                    <Select labelId="demo-simple-select-label" id="demo-simple-select" value={roles}
                                               onChange={onRankChange}>
                                        <MenuItem value="one">one</MenuItem>
                                        <MenuItem value="two">two</MenuItem>
                                        <MenuItem value="three">three</MenuItem>
                                        <MenuItem value="four">four</MenuItem>
                                    </Select>

const [ranks, setRanks] = useState("");

 const onRankChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown}>) => {

            console.log('inside role change');
            if(event.target.value === "one"){
                setRanks(event.target.value as string);
                setLeft(["test","test1","test2"]);
                setRight(["test3","test4"]);
            }
            else if(event.target.value === "two"){
                setRanks(event.target.value as string);
                setLeft(["test3","test4"]);
                setRight( ["test","test1","test2"]);
            }
            else if(event.target.value === "three"){
                setRanks(event.target.value as string);
                setLeft( []);
                setRight( ["test","test1","test2","test3","test4"]);
            }
            else if(event.target.value === "four"){
                setRanks(event.target.value as string);
                setLeft(["test","test1","test2","test3","test4"]);
                setRight( []);
            }

            console.log('roles####' +event.target.value);
            console.log('leftChecked###' + left);
            console.log('rightChecked####' + right);
    }


Why are you printing the values if, as you wrote, functionality wise it is working? Are you planning to change the prints to something else in the future?

The issue looks like it might be related to the asynchronous nature of state updates in React. When you call setLeft and setRight, React schedules these state updates, but they don't happen immediately. As a result, when you try to log left and right immediately after setting them, you might still see their previous values.
I always use useEffect to handle side effects in this case. I tried editing your code a bit and it should be logging the correct values:
So, the state is:
 const [roles, setRoles] = useState("");
 const [left, setLeft] = useState([]);
 const [right, setRight] = useState([]);

and the function to change the ranks:
const onRankChange = (event) => {
    const selectedValue = event.target.value;

    console.log("inside role change");
    if (selectedValue === "one") {
      setRoles(selectedValue);
      setLeft(["test", "test1", "test2"]);
      setRight(["test3", "test4"]);
    } else if (selectedValue === "two") {
      setRoles(selectedValue);
      setLeft(["test3", "test4"]);
      setRight(["test", "test1", "test2"]);
    } else if (selectedValue === "three") {
      setRoles(selectedValue);
      setLeft([]);
      setRight(["test", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]);
    } else if (selectedValue === "four") {
      setRoles(selectedValue);
      setLeft(["test", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]);
      setRight([]);
    }

    console.log("roles####" + selectedValue);
  };

and most importantly, you need to use the useEffect, (or at least what I would use) to react to changes in state and perform actions like logging after the state has been updated.
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("leftChecked###" + left);
    console.log("rightChecked####" + right);
  }, [left, right]); // Depend on left and right so it runs after they are updated

I created codesanbox, you might check the code in that.

Thank you so much for the answer..but unfortunately it is not working in my actual code. I am using react 4 will that make any difference as I am beginner in react

React 4? I'm not quite sure if you mean the react-router.
